# How to use angular states and nested views for my three panel design?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, viewstate

I am learning angular js and I have start with simple todo app. But I am confused with ui views, states and directives.
I also need the data available in all three states. this is where I am stuck right now, I need to put it in $rootScope which is not good practice. I also want to assign different controllers to all three panels

Here is the full code https://github.com/udayghulaxe/ticitic_todo

What I want is this 
[This is my app strucutre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8uZt.png)

I want a list of project in first panel, then list of tasks in second panel,and then tasks detail in third 
What I have done so far is this.

```js
$stateProvider
.state('dashboard', {
 url: '/dashboard',
 abstract: true,
 views: {
 '': { templateUrl: './partials/main.html'},
 'header_toolbar@dashboard': { templateUrl: './views/header_toolbar.html' },
 'sidenavleft@dashboard': { templateUrl: './views/sidenav.html' },
 'widgets@dashboard': { templateUrl: './views/widgets.html'},
 'todo_detail@dashboard': { templateUrl: './views/todo_detail.html' }
 }
})
.state('dashboard.listdetail', {
 url: '/lists/:list_id/',
 templateUrl: './partials/list.detail.html',
 controller:'ListController',
 resolve: {
  list_id: function($stateParams){
   return $stateParams.list_id;
  }
 },
 data: {
  authorizedRoles: [USER_ROLES.user],
  pageTitle: 'Lists'
 }
})
.state('dashboard.tododetail', {
 url: '/lists/:list_id/:todo_id',
 templateUrl: './partials/list.detail.html',
 controller:'ListController',
 resolve: {
  list_id: function($stateParams){
   console.log($stateParams);
   return $stateParams.list_id;
  }
  ,
  todo_id: function($stateParams){
   console.log($stateParams);
   return $stateParams.todo_id;
  }
 }
});
```

```html
<div id="appContainer" md-theme="{{ dynamicTheme }}" ng-init="load()" md-theme-watch>
  <!-- Header Toolbar -->
  <div ui-view="header_toolbar"></div>

  <div layout="row" layout-xs="column" layout-sm="column">
    <!-- Sidenav right view -->
    <div ui-view="sidenavleft" id="nav_container"></div>

    <!-- Main middle container  -->
    <div flex="100" flex-gt-sm="55"  layout="column" id="list_content">
        <md-content layout="column" flex class="md-padding">
            <div ui-view></div>
        </md-content>
    </div>

    <!-- Todo Detail View -->
    <div ui-view="todo_detail" id="todo_detail_view"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

can someone please help me writing correct structure(ui states) for my app.

Comment: see this plunkr http://embed.plnkr.co/IzimSVsstarlFviAm7S7/preview

Comment: @DurgpalSingh I am facing a problem to transfer data to task detail panel.
I have data available inside <md-content> scope but my todo_detail view is outside the scope of my controller and hence I have to pass data using $rootScope, I want to access data without putting it into rootscope

Comment: then you can that variable with $stateParams